# Alignment image

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a site which needs an image centered in the div on the left side, centered off the right div with a background.

I tried to a common solution, but for some reason, it won't work. It must be responsive as well, so I'm a bit in the dark over here. See my fiddle for the example.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
  <div class="leftSide">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3755760/pexels-photo-3755760.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="img-fluid imgLeft">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
  <div class="rightSide">
    <h3>
    Some text
    </h3>
    <p>
    Some more text 
    </p>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Some text</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Onno0297/grvwxby2/1/

Comment: Is this bootstrap? You need to tag it as such.

Comment: Can you be more specific? You need two images, one in the right div and the other in the left div. Both are centered. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then below code will work.

Visit https://jsfiddle.net/alishapatel/n3ap1vjo/4/!

```css
.leftSide {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.rightSide {
  background: #313131;
  height: 546px;
  color: #fff;
}

.rightSide h3 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 200px;
}

.rightSide p {
  text-align: center;
}
.btn.btn-primary {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

.imgLeft {
  max-height: 400px;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="leftSide">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3755760/pexels-photo-3755760.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="img-fluid imgLeft">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="rightSide">
        <h3>
        Some text
        </h3>
        <p>
        Some more text 
        </p>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Some text</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```